# PHP Form Input Checked

Tags: php

So I am starting to learn PHP and I am having an issue. So a file "store.php" will collect data from login page and the login page ask for an email and password. 
I'm trying to make regexs to check if the email is valid and if the password contains: at least 1 digits, 1 uppercase, 1 lower case, 1 special character and is minimum length is 8. Somehow nothing gets checked and It brings me directly to canvas.php which I get it because I do "actions ="canvas.php"" in the form. Anyone could help me out?

```
<?php
$email =  $password = "";
$emailERR = $psswrdERR = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$email = test_email($_POST["email"]);
$password = test_psswrd($_POST["password"]);
}

function test_psswrd($data) {
  if(!(preg_match('/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}/', $data))){ 
   $password = "Password is not valid";
   return $password;
}
  else{
    return $data;
  }

}

function test_email($data)
{
  $data = trim($data);
  if (filter_var($data, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
  {
    return $data;
  } 
  else 
  {
    $emailERR = "Email is not valid";
    return $emailERR;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did action=canvas.php in the form, then this code will never run, as you're never posting to this page. If you want to do validations, make sure you're posting to the file that's actually doing the validation.

Furthermore- this code should raise an exception and return the correct status if the email/password are invalid- it looks like you're not doing anything special in test_password or test_email.

Comment: OH! In both test funcion I am trying to verify if they are valid or not